# HiGHS solver for PyPSA-EUR

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, pypsa

I am trying to use HiGHS solver for PyPSA-Eur. By setting it in config.yaml like:

```
  solver:
    name: highs
    options: {}
```

It throws following error:

> RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.
>
> The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "highs" and returned
> an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point where the
> UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling method
> "has_capability").
>
> The original solver was created with the following parameters:
> executable: highs
> type: highs
> _args: ()
> options: {}

while creating the environment highspy gets installed properly and no issues there.

While in the `pypsa-eur` environment if i do  `python -c "import highspy"` it does not throw any error that means highspy is there to be used.

How can we configure pypsa to use HiGHS as a solver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to build `HiGHS` from https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS and it worked. Also HiGHS shared lib path has to be included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so the dynamically linked lib can be found.

After building HiGHS from source the executable can be found in:

> /HiGHS/build/bin/

One might need to create a symlink or provide a complete path to the executable.

It seems that HiGHS was not able to handle network clustering in PyPSA-Eur

```
if not opt.has_capability("quadratic_objective"):
        logger.warning(
            f"The configured solver `{solver_name}` does not support quadratic objectives. Falling back to `ipopt`."
        )
        opt = po.SolverFactory("ipopt")
    
    results = opt.solve(m, tee=True)
```

When using HiGHS the error was encountered at `results = opt.solve(m, tee=True)` so as a workaround I used `ipopt` by default for `cluster_network` rule (snakemake) and used HiGHS to solve the model.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you use

```yaml
  solver:
    name: highs
    options: highs-default
```

First line defines the solver, second line defines the options to use for the solver.

Comment: thanks, i tried by specifying `highs-default`  instead of `{}` but it throws same error. I think the exception occurs at the step where solver instance is created. `The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "highs" `

Answer (score 1):

Should you be on Windows, it might be that you have to install HiGHS binaries manually. Not sure.

https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/stable/installation/

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I have tried building highs from source and adding it to the path but it still gives an error. Seems like a bug in pypsa itself and/or the interface they are using to communicate with HiGHS